# “work with” or "work for"?

Tags: phrase-usage

[Trade Truce by China and U.S. Gives Both Sides Political Breathing Room](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/12/02/business/trade-truce-china-us.html?action=click&module=Top%20Stories&pgtype=Homepage)

> “China has emphasized many times that United States bullying and
>   pressure **aren’t working with** China,” Gao Feng, the Commerce Ministry
>   spokesman, said in a briefing on Oct. 11.

With doubt, I looked up the original Chinese text. I used translator to translate it is

> China has repeatedly stressed that US bullying and extreme pressure **do
>   not work for** China.

I feel "work for" is appropriate and "work with" like "work with sb".
And I don't understand why it is the present continuous tense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"work for China"` only makes sense if China is **doing the action**.

`"It's not working for me,"` as I attempt something and fail.

`"That won't work with him,"` as I attempt to pressure or trick someone. You can also say `"work on"` to mean `"have an effect on"`.

So, to answer you:
`"bullying and pressure won't work with China"` and `"bullying and pressure won't work on China"` are both correct. `"work for"` would only make sense if China was the one bullying.